# How do I set up different workflows for the same ticket type in different jira projects?

Tags: jira

We have had a restructure of our engineering teams and a wide ranging change to process, as a result we have decided to start a new Jira Project.

We want to keep the existing Ticket Types but our new process will require changes to Jira Workflows. However as we dont want to lose our old project in case there are tickets we decide to Migrate over we want to ensure that the workflows etc for that board do not change.

Is it possible to have different workflows for the same ticket types in Jira at a project level, or am I going to have to create everything from scratch again (Tickets, workflows, screens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jira you can reuse every mentioned thing.

Create another one workflow scheme for second project and make you own issue type<>workflow mapping inside it scheme. Create new workflow if you want make another process for your issues. You can do it a bit easy if changes is minor - just copy base workflow and make you changes instead creating new.

[Docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-workflow-schemes-938847421.html)